# HP Mini refuses to boot, won't even display BIOS

Tags: laptop

I have an HP Mini 210-1170NR and recently the battery expired. It worked fine when plugged into the wall, but today it won't show the HP logo or anything; just gets stuck with the caps lock light on. hard disk is spinning, but computer is unresponsive. This happens the second it's powered on so it's likely not the OS.

What could be wrong and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a bad graphics card, cpu, or monitor. If you plug in an external monitor does it work?  In all 3 cases there isn't much you can do.  I would send it to HP.

Comment: CPU gets warm as if in use; harddisk makes normals sounds- might be ram or cpu; only one of which I'd be able to access

Comment: Even if it was the N455 cannot be replaced by you nor HP. They likely would replace the entire motherboard if this was under a service contract.

Comment: warranty expired last year :(

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of many things, most of them unfortunately fatal and not something you can repair yourself (or get someone else to repair for much less than the cost of replacing the machine with something new). As the battery has expired I assume it is no longer under warranty, so you probably can't return it to the manufacturer and ask them to sort it.

On the off-chance that it is just the display (or the ribbon cable to it) that is malfunctioning, try plugging it into an external monitor.

If it can't be repaired and you don't have backups of your data all is not lost in that respect, assuming the drive is OK which from your description it probably is. These units, like most netbooks, use standard 2.5" drives so you can remove it and put it into a SATA->USB enclosure in order to read off the data (or just us it in-place) - and you now have a handy external drive that you can use as part of your backup strategy when you get a replacement the machine. Getting in to the drive isn't terribly easy but there are tutorials out there, [like this one for example](http://www.overclock.net/t/737360/how-to-upgrade-the-hard-drive-in-a-hp-mini-210).

*If you didn't have backups of your data, do make sure you arrange a good backup arrangement ASAP, it could save you a lot of stress in the future!*

Comment: external monitor didn't help; the hard disk should be easy to access. at this point the fact I'm down one unit is probably the worst part :/